# ifthenelse to ignore a section

Tags: macros

I am writing a textbook which has a student version and a teacher version. I did this:

```
\newboolean{teach}

\setboolean{teach}{true}

\newcommand{\teachr}[1]{\ifthenelse{\boolean{teach}}{\begin{teacher}{#1}\end{teacher}}{\begin{comment}#1\end{comment}}}
```

to make a command that would print a specific way for teacher sections but can be easily commented out for a student version. I tested the teacher environment and it works fine. But the `\teachr` command does not set as comment when

```
\setboolean{teach}{false}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `comment` package already has the needed infrastructure: `\excludecomment{teacher}` is the key.

Comment: I wonder where the `section` occurs in this question?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I wonder where the *example* occurs in this question...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @cfr: I gave up to wonder about missing examples in questions ;-)

Comment: Does `\newcommand{\teachr}[1]{\ifthenelse{\boolean{teach}}{\begin{teacher}{#1}\end{teacher}}{\relax}}` work?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are trying to do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}

\newif\ifTeacher\Teachertrue
\newcommand\teacher[1]{\ifTeacher#1\else\relax\fi}

\begin{document}

\teacher{This is a remark for the teacher}

\Teacherfalse

\teacher{This should be ignored.}

This is for everyone.

\end{document}
```

By using `\Teachertrue` and `\Teacherfalse` you can toggle whether or not the argument passed to `\teacher` is printed. The example code above produces:
[image]